# What is the best way to debug try-catch blocks in Uipath studio

Tags: rpa, uipath

What is the best way to debug try-catch blocks in Uipath studio - now it is too slow as it breaks on every catch

Comment: Not too sure what you mean with the question. Are you asking how to debug with the try-catch activity/best practice of using them?

Comment: the problem was that when I used the try-catch activity for big container of data (table with 500 rows or more) with the latest version of uipath studio it is very difficult (nearly impossible)  to debug the process,however I used 'if' activity to debug after that I replaced it with 't-c' but it wasn't very convenient solution. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

If you are stressed with the breaks. Simply use the **Run mode** instead of the **Debug mode**.

This will work as long as the error just happens in the Try Catch blocks tho.